# Check Dropbox Datastore API for Previous Sync (iOS)

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

My goal is to check a user's datastores to see if they previously synced data to the default datastore. If they did, I'll pull down and sync all their data. If they didn't, I'll push their local data to Dropbox.

I've tried a number of things to check for the existence of data, but I'm getting inconsistent results.

I set up a button tap to try a certain bit of code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSyncDropbox:(id)sender {

  //Initiate a Datastore
  DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
  self.store = [DBDatastore openDefaultStoreForAccount:account error:nil];

  //Sync so our local copy matches the server
  [self.store sync:nil];

  //Check if there is an "aircraft" table already
  DBTable *currentTable = [self.store getTable:@"aircraft"];
  NSArray *list = [currentTable query:nil error:nil];

  NSLog(@"%@",list);

  /* Half the time, the log output shows this:
  "(null)" 

  ...and this the other half:

  (
      "DBRecord(89BvrTEcSElewsFhw0B1mg)",
      "DBRecord(PpGb17BNF3Psn7jR2skZkQ)"
  )
  */
}
```

Shouldn't I see a list of records in my `aircraft` table every time I execute this code? The lack of consistency is difficult to work with. Am I supposed to be listening for this data with an observer or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that it's a race condition. The first time you link an account, it will take time before the data is loaded, and you need to set up an observer to wait for that initial sync to take place.

*Perhaps* some of the confusion is here:

```
//Sync so our local copy matches the server
[self.store sync:nil];
```

That's not what `sync` does. `sync` does two things:

1. Queue up any local changes since the last call to `sync` to get sent to the server later (asynchronously).
2. Apply any remote changes that have already been downloaded to the local copy of the datastore.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. So would `DBAccount` be the appropriate thing to observe to know if the account linking is done?

Comment: To wait for the initial datastore snapshot to be downloaded, I think you need to watch the `DBDatastoreStatus` of the `DBDatastore` and wait for `DBDatastoreDownloading` to not be set. (It should be set when you first open the datastore until the snapshot with the server has completed.)